# Normal map baking issue

Tags: sculpting, baking, normal-map

I searched a lot for answers on this but couldn't find any solution that would fix the issue. In the image below you can see that the normal map is not exactly.. normal. I tried playing around with extrusion and ray distance, but this was the best result I could get out of it. Any ideas? The image texture is set to 32 bit, I've unwrapped both meshes and applied all their transforms.
[image]

Comment: the rays meet inverted faces, hard to say without the file but it probably happens around the armpits and groin, maybe share your file? you could paint these parts with a blue color for example

Comment: Moonboots is right.  Even without file (which I'd want to write a real answer), I can say: 1) disable max ray distance (set to 0), you don't want that; 2) you probably need a higher extrusion value.  Personally, I recommend using a displace modifier instead of extrusion: same thing, but you get visual feedback.  It's not impossible that there is no value for extrusion that is correct, at which point you would consider using a cage.

Comment: I tried uploading the file via blend-exchange but for some reason it won't process my file, I don't know why, it's only 13mb, but I've read on the forum that there might be some issues with blender 3 and above files.. Anyway, here is a google drive link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cKl2ALSGYPPOWHRTFEaHU1vJHS2n7e0H/view?usp=drive_link .But yes, moonboots got it right, it happens around the armpits and groin. I tried recalculating the sculpt normals, playing around with the displace modifier, with no max ray distance, but nothing helps..

Comment: Hello, the link asksfor an authorization   ;)

Comment: AH sorry, check it now please https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cKl2ALSGYPPOWHRTFEaHU1vJHS2n7e0H/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I ended up adjusting the map manually in texture paint, since there weren't many areas with issues, but I'm still open to other solutions apart from this or the cage, which can e time consuming.

Comment: I can't get a better result than yours so what you could do is correct the colors or you could bake a second map with a low Extrusion value and mix it with the first one?

Comment: That's an interesting idea. but I think it's faster to edit the map in texture paint, or at least depending on the surface that needs to be corrected.